# I am trying to register users in django but the form fields are not showing up. What is wrong with my code?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

this is my forms.py:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, fields
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
   class Meta:
      model = User
      fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

This is my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .forms import CreateUserForm
def RegisterPage(request):
    form = CreateUserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'register.html', context)
```

this is my html template:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 login-bg">
        <h4 class="reg-title"><strong>Get Started...</strong></h4>
        <p class="login-reg">Already have an account? <a class="log-reg-link" href="login.html">Log In </a> here</p>
        <hr>

        <form class="" action="/Dashboard/" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <p class="reg-field-title"><strong>Username*</strong></p>
            <div>{{form.username}}</div>

            <p class="reg-field-title"><strong>Email ID*</strong></p>
            <div>{{form.email}}</div>

            <p class="reg-field-title"><strong>Password*</strong></p>
            <div>{{form.password1}}</div>

            <p class="reg-field-title"><strong>Password Confirmation*</strong></p>
            <div>{{form.password2}}</div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg col-lg-10 reg-btn">Register</button>
        </form>
```

What am I doing wrong because the form fields are not showing up on the page? I followed a youtube tutorial and went step by step but I don't understand the problem now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your view.py.

```
def RegisterPage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = CreateUserForm()
    return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form})
```

Add this in your urls.py

```
 path("login/", views.RegisterPage,  name='register'),
```